# Are there BLAS and LAPACK libraries that are written in C and do not need a FORTRAN compiler to build?

Tags: c++, c

At the best source of documentation for [BLAS](https://www.netlib.org/blas/), there is mention of "The netlib family and cousins." In that, there is a mention of [BLAS++](https://bitbucket.org/icl/blaspp/src/master/) and [LAPACK++](https://bitbucket.org/icl/lapackpp/src/master/). However, both of those `C++` libraries are just wrappers to Fortran code.

I want to use BLAS and LAPACK, but don’t want to enforce a Fortran compiler be available on the system for my users. Are there any optimized BLAS and LAPACK libraries (analogous to OpenBLAS) that have been written in C/C++?

Comment: Is [CLAPACK](https://www.netlib.org/clapack/) what you are looking for?

Comment: This seems to be more of a programming related question that may be better on StackOverflow

Comment: @DeveloperACE SO told me to come over here

Comment: ok ok, go with that then lol, i probably dont understand where exactly the line is